# Use function from another class or struct in a function within this class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, hashtable

I am creating a hash table and need to have this chained hash table tested with different hash functions. 
I have hash structs such as

```
struct Hasher {
    virtual int hash(std::string s, int N) = 0;
};

struct SumHasher : Hasher {
    int hash(std::string s, int N){
        int result = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)
            result += s[i];
        return int (std::abs((int)result)) % N;
    }
};
struct ProdHasher : Hasher {
    int hash(std::string s, int N) {
        int result = 1;
        for (int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)
        result *= s[i];
    return int (std::abs((int)result)) % N;
    }
};
struct ShiftHasher : Hasher {
    int hash(std::string s, int N){
    const int shift = 6; unsigned z = 0;
    const int mask = ~z >> (32-shift); // lower 6 bits on
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        result = (result << shift) | (s[i] & mask);
    return int (std::abs((int)result)) % N;
    }
};
```

Now how can I use this functions within the Hashtable class by creating a struct hash type then passing that object to the constructor

```
class ChainedHashTable
{

    ListNode **T; // array of linked lists
    int capacity;
public:
    Hasher *myhash;
    int info;
    ChainedHashTable(int numberOfChains, Hasher *myHasher){
        myhash = hasher;
        capacity = numberOfChains;
       T = new ListNode* [capacity];
       for (int i=0; i<capacity; ++i)
           T[i] = NULL;
     }
.......
void ChainedHashTable::insert(std::string key, int info){
    int h = myhash::hash(key, capacity);
    T[h] = ListNode::make(key, info, T[h]);
}
```

Comment: `myhash->hash(key, capacity)`?

Comment: myhash->hash(key, capacity)

Comment: WOW THANKS, that was stupid of me...

Comment: @Tangleman your on the virtual use, and I get that, but you could remove that dependency and simply use a template instead (similar to how `std::unordered_map<>` and `std::unordered_set<>` do their thing. A hash function should be tightly bound to the table it is hashing, and it doesn't look like it would be terrible to make it happen. Just a suggestion, but food for thought. Anyway, best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

you should use:

```
myhash->hash(key, capacity)
```

Comment: Actually i just realized this doesnt work, I need to create that struct class first and then pass that object into Hashtables constructor as a refrence i guess. how would i do that?

Comment: never mind I could just pass that object as &object so its a pointer. thanks for the answer!